# FastAPI: How to use enums for the BaseModel schema

Tags: python, enums, database-schema, fastapi, mode

I want to use a enum field at my FastAPI model. This is my model:

```
import enum

from sqlalchemy import Column, Enum, Integer, String

class Gender(enum.Enum):
    FEMALE = "FEMALE"
    MALE = "MALE"
    ...


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
   
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    gender Column(Enum(Gender), default=Gender.FEMALE)
```

And this is my schema:

```
from enum import Enum

from pydantic import BaseModel

class Gender(str, Enum):
   FEMALE = 'FEMALE'
   MALE = 'MALE'
   ...


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    gender: Gender

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I get the error message `value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'FEMALE', 'MALE' (type=type_error.enum; enum_values=[<Gender.FEMALE: 'FEMALE'>, <Gender.MALE: 'MALE'>])`.

**Update:**

Now I get the error message: `pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for IdentificationRequestBase response -> 0 -> gender field required (type=value_error.missing)`.

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370808/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76131490/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 3):

For MongoDB follow this :

1. Create schema.py file

```py
from enum import Enum

class Gender(str,Enum):
    Male = 'Male'
    Female = "Female"
```

2. Next use **Gender** class in your main BaseModel

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    gender: Gender
```

3. Now use **User class** in you `main.py` file

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a file called enums.py where you only declare Gender:

```
from enum import Enum, unique


@unique
class Gender(Enum):
    FEMALE = "FEMALE"
    MALE = "MALE"
```

And then in your models use it like this:

```
from enums import Gender

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    gender = Column(Enum(Gender), default=Gender.FEMALE)
```

And in your schemas try this:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    gender: Gender

class Config:
    orm_mode = True
```

Comment: `ValueError: <enum 'Role'> is not a valid Enum`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the default simply as a string:

```py
    gender = Column(Enum(Gender), default="FEMALE")
```

---

If that still does not help, try to change `default` to `server_default`:

```py
    gender = Column(Enum(Gender), server_default="FEMALE")
```

---

If you want to default to `None` for the schema, you can also make the field optional:

```py
from typing import Optional

class User(BaseModel):

        gender: Optional[Gender]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried your proposals, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how I was able to fix it.

import `Gender` from `your_model.py` file in `your_schemas.py` file

this is how `your_schemas.py` file should look like

```
from 'your_model' import Gender
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    gender: Gender #from 'your_model.py'

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```