Matching a string input against a Python enum
I'm want to do a basic case-insensitive match against some set of strings, as in the following code:
class Fruit(Enum):
    APPLE = "Apple"
    ORANGE = "Orange"
    BANANA = "Banana"


def match_fruit(s: str) -> Fruit | None:
    s = s.lower()
    for fruit in Fruit:
        if fruit.value.lower() == s:
            return fruit
    return None

Is there some idiomatic equivalent to match_fruit that's built into the Enum class so that I don't have to write this boilerplate code all the time?  Note: I don't want my enum values to be lowercase, because they might be used in other contexts where I want them to appear as CamelCase or whatever.

No, I don't think there's any built-in case-insensitive searching.

I think there is no built-in features like this for Enum, but I have found this answer that could help you, please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76131490/17274446

In this example, you can simply try to return Fruit(s.title()), which will either produce the desired instance or raise a ValueError that you can catch. There's no need to force both s and instances of Fruit to a lowercase string.

You want the _missing_ method:
class Fruit(Enum):
    #
    APPLE = "Apple"
    ORANGE = "Orange"
    BANANA = "Banana"
    #
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        s = s.lower()
        for fruit in Fruit:
            if fruit.value.lower() == s:
                return fruit
        return None


You can do something like:
'ORANGE' in Fruit.__members__
>>> True

to get a match on the KEY
otherwise you need to do:
'Orange' in [v.value for v in Fruit.__members__.values()]
>>> True

to get a match on the value
But it looks like you are misusing Enum for your purpose. You might want to use a set or array to hold your values and just use
fruits = ['Orange', 'Banana', 'Apple']
'Orange' in fruits
>>> True

As far as case insensitivity, whichever option you choose, there is not much other way than to iterate and lowercase both sides.

I found a solution that works reasonably well for my purpose:
def match_fruit(s: str) -> Fruit:
    """Return a case-insensitive Fruit match on the given string, or raise KeyError"""
    return Fruit[s.upper()]

This assumes that the variable-name keys (APPLE, ORANGE) are always the direct uppercase of the corresponding values ("Apple", "Orange") but that's not a problematic constraint, as it still allows Fruit.APPLE.value to be whatever I want, as long as it's a valid Python identifier that doesn't include special characters.  Snake-Case wouldn't work.
